# Undefined Index in codeigniter in my project

Tags: codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

**Message: Undefined index: ccover**

Filename: Admin_controller/Admin_categories_con.php

Line Number: 39

Backtrace:

File: /home3/acropoli/bharatphoton.acropolisglobal/application/controllers/Admin_controller/Admin_categories_con.php
Line: 39
Function: _error_handler

```
<?php
class Admin_categories_con extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('AdminLoginModel');
    $categories = $this->AdminLoginModel->cat_list();
    $this->load->view('Admin_panel/Admin_categories', ['categories'=>$categories ], array('error' =>''));

}

public function test()
{
    echo "Category add successfully";
}


 public function catadd()
{


    $config = [
        'upload_path' => '../uploads',
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif',
        ];
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->model('AdminLoginModel');
    $data_form= $this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);

    if($data_form && !$this->upload->do_upload())

    {
    $this->load->model('AdminLoginModel');
    $data_form= $this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);

    if($data_form && !$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $cname=$data_form['cname'];
        $ccover=$data_form['ccover'];

   $data=array(
       'cname'=>$cname,
       'ccover'=>$ccover,
       );     

       $this->AdminLoginModel->catadd($data);
       redirect('Admin_controller/Admin_categories_con/test');
    }

    $this->load->view('Admin_panel/Admin_categories'); 
} 
else
{
$this->index();
}
}
}
```

// Here is my view file //

```
<div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">
 <?php include APPPATH.'views/Admin_panel/Admin_header1.php'; ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('Admin_controller/Admin_categories_con/catadd'); ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="page-header float-left">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h1>CATEGORIES</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content mt-3">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                           <div class="col col-md-3"><label for="select" class=" form-control-label">Add new Categories</label>
                           </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                                    <input type="text" id="text-input" name="cname" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group"> 
                           <div class="col col-md-3"><label for="select" class=" form-control-label">Categories Image</label>
                           </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                                    <input type="file" id="text-input" name="ccover" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                        </div>
                       <div class="row form-group">
                           <div class="col col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block">Submit</button>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table">
                                <thead class="thead-dark">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">S.no</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Category Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Image</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Action</th>    
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                   <?php if(count($categories) ): ?>
                                    <?php $index=0; ?>

                                        <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                                        <?php $index++; ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $index; ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $category->cname ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $category->ccover ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $category->cstatus ?></td>

                                        <td><button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <?php endforeach; ?>

                                <?php else: ?>
                                     <tr>
                                         <td colspan="6">
                                             No Record Found
                                         </td>
                                     </tr> 

                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>
             </div>  
        </div>

    </div> 
     <?php include APPPATH.'views/Admin_panel/Admin_footer.php'; ?>
</div>

   <?php include APPPATH.'views/Admin_panel/Admin_script.php'; ?>
   </form>
```

Comment: Where you are calling `Admin_categories_con.php` in controller?

Comment: Can you please show your view file code. I believe you have used different spelling there for "ccover".

Comment: yes i am calling Admin_categories_con.php my  views Admin_categories.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot get input type file in post element ... in order to get filename ... codeigniter has upload class has method data .. from where you can have file name ... so 
in order to upload file

```
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('ccover'))
        {
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
        }
```

do_upload method force you file to upload ..... and you can get file name after that

change

```
$ccover = $data_form['ccover'];
```

to

```
$ccover = $this->upload->data('file_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure $ccover variable is sent to php ?